# R how to get summary function to work on censReg package models

Tags: r, dplyr, summary

I am attempting to use the censReg function in R which is part of the censReg package.  I am attempting to model fish biomass data that are continuous in nature and include zeroes.  Zero is the lowest value possible because there is no such thing as negative biomass.  I decided to use the censReg package as a way to deal with the heavily zero-inflated, continuous distribution of the total_biomass response variable.  I have been successful in getting the model provided below to run, however when I attempt to run the summary() function on the model, I receive the following error:

```
Error in printCoefmat(coef(x, logSigma = logSigma), digits = digits) : 
  'x' must be coefficient matrix/data frame
```

Looking at this error message, I do not understand what it means nor what the issue is with my code or database.  Can anyone provide me any additional code or tweaks I need to make in order to successfully obtain the model summary?

### Datebase

```
library(tidyverse)
library(censReg)

mean_fish_totals <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L), .Label = c("11/28/17", 
"12/10/19", "12/14/19", "12/3/17", "12/4/18", "12/8/18", "2/25/17", 
"3/19/19", "3/22/19", "4/18/17", "5/15/18", "5/20/18", "5/25/17", 
"6/3/19", "6/4/19", "6/6/17", "8/28/18", "9/1/18", "9/10/19", 
"9/15/19", "9/20/16", "9/22/16", "9/25/16", "9/27/16", "9/5/17", 
"9/7/17"), class = "factor"), `Module #` = c(211L, 212L, 213L, 
214L, 215L, 216L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 111L, 112L, 
113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 211L, 
212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 
111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 
216L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 
215L, 216L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 
114L, 115L, 116L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 111L, 112L, 
113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 211L, 
212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 
111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 
216L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 
114L, 115L, 116L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 211L, 212L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 
214L, 215L, 216L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L), Site_long = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Hanauma Bay", 
"Waikiki"), class = "factor"), Treatment_long = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Closed", 
"Open"), class = "factor"), Shelter = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("High", 
"Low"), class = "factor"), TimeStep = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 
0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 0.75, 2, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), total_biomass = c(0.0526394784788566, 
0.00650991088549517, 0.180596698411345, 0, 0.526717015131238, 
0, 0.206894204748519, 0.0164498212264971, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.201603325166693, 
0, 0.283172330030785, 0, 0, 0, 0.209199851062596, 0, 0.283172330030785, 
0, 0.394899281159044, 0.176129136061979, 0.169586003898729, 0, 
0.120034320302602, 0, 0.996727938559748, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.257380940140258, 
0.443609909402316, 0.308392987176445, 0, 0.748305018557033, 0, 
0.169586003898729, 0, 0.120034320302602, 0, 0.120034320302602, 
0, 1.08474493759439, 0, 0, 0.0745413774887557, 0, 0.0467403151010407, 
0.233352036920048, 0, 0.0899664423257818, 0, 0.308392987176445, 
0, 0, 0, 10.6461511880577, 0, 26.4504921170652, 0, 0.526717015131238, 
0, 0, 0, 0.403061371653634, 0.209695276260751, 0.120034320302602, 
0.0206199419933497, 0.078489026854395, 0, 0.165344302422082, 
0, 0.0317487117533543, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.94950027744447, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1.03519325399826, 0, 0.169586003898729, 0.125258604363503, 
0.310810458426215, 0, 10.6461511880577, 0, 0, 0, 0.976669817356845, 
0, 0.996727938559748, 0, 0, 0.0202327772014947, 0.0403651893214743, 
0, 0.168776380464422, 0, 0.133454408606973, 0, 0, 0.621724957549784, 
0.0164498212264971, 0, 0.110237738607749, 0, 0.116136901985565, 
0, 0, 0.0135959326713389, 0.00889824575015321, 0.078489026854395, 
0.16627064788403, 0, 0.028053154008064, 0.0526394784788566, 0.0419621766803908, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.308392987176445, 0.0520989800170256, 0.222619650542138, 
0, 21.2935111117403, 15.7227719241434, 0.232861857335555, 0, 
0.0634974235067086, 0, 0.0492074004365164, 0), new_date = structure(c(17498, 
17498, 17498, 17498, 17498, 17498, 18240, 18240, 18240, 18240, 
18240, 18240, 18244, 18244, 18244, 18244, 18244, 18244, 17503, 
17503, 17503, 17503, 17503, 17503, 17869, 17869, 17869, 17869, 
17869, 17869, 17873, 17873, 17873, 17873, 17873, 17873, 17222, 
17222, 17222, 17222, 17222, 17222, 17974, 17974, 17974, 17974, 
17974, 17974, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17274, 
17274, 17274, 17274, 17274, 17274, 17666, 17666, 17666, 17666, 
17666, 17666, 17671, 17671, 17671, 17671, 17671, 17671, 17311, 
17311, 17311, 17311, 17311, 17311, 18050, 18050, 18050, 18050, 
18050, 18050, 18051, 18051, 18051, 18051, 18051, 18051, 17323, 
17323, 17323, 17323, 17323, 17323, 17771, 17771, 17771, 17771, 
17771, 17771, 17775, 17775, 17775, 17775, 17775, 17775, 18149, 
18149, 18149, 18149, 18149, 18149, 18154, 18154, 18154, 18154, 
18154, 18154, 17064, 17064, 17064, 17064, 17066, 17066, 17066, 
17069, 17069, 17069, 17071, 17071, 17414, 17414, 17414, 17414, 
17414, 17414, 17416, 17416, 17416, 17416, 17416, 17416), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-144L), groups = structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L), .Label = c("11/28/17", "12/10/19", "12/14/19", "12/3/17", 
"12/4/18", "12/8/18", "2/25/17", "3/19/19", "3/22/19", "4/18/17", 
"5/15/18", "5/20/18", "5/25/17", "6/3/19", "6/4/19", "6/6/17", 
"8/28/18", "9/1/18", "9/10/19", "9/15/19", "9/20/16", "9/22/16", 
"9/25/16", "9/27/16", "9/5/17", "9/7/17"), class = "factor"), 
    `Module #` = c(211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 211L, 
    212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 
    116L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 
    214L, 215L, 216L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 111L, 
    112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 
    216L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 
    214L, 215L, 216L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 111L, 
    112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 
    116L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 
    214L, 215L, 216L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 211L, 
    212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 
    116L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 
    114L, 115L, 116L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 
    111L, 112L, 113L, 211L, 212L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 
    216L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L), Site_long = c("Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki"), Treatment_long = c("Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed"), Shelter = c("High", "Low", "High", 
    "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
    "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
    "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
    "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
    "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
    "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
    "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
    "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
    "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
    "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
    "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
    "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
    "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
    "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
    "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
    "Low", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "High", 
    "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
    "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low"), .rows = list(1L, 2L, 
        3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
        15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
        26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
        37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
        48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 
        59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 
        70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
        81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 
        92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 
        103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 
        112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 
        121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 
        130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 
        139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-144L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

### Analysis

```
## Herbivorous fish with interaction
# variables
module_fish <- mean_fish_totals$`Module #`

# Data distribution #
plotNormalHistogram(mean_fish_totals$total_biomass)

## Generalized Mixed Effects Model Fishes ##
# glmer new database #
mean_fish_totals$Shelter <- factor(mean_fish_totals$Shelter, levels = c("Low", "High"), ordered = TRUE)
mean_fish_totals$Site_long <- as.factor(mean_fish_totals$Site_long)

# Censreg Model #
fish_mixed_effects_censreg <- censReg(total_biomass ~ Site_long*Shelter + (1|module_fish), left = 0, right = Inf, data = mean_fish_totals)
summary(fish_mixed_effects_censreg)
```

Thanks in advance for your input!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the part "(1|module_fish)" because censReg() does not "know" this way of specifying the regression formula. If you have panel data, cenReg() can account for random effects in the intercept (see "vignette" to the censReg package) but not account for random effects in the slope parameters. You can estimate a model without random effects by:

```
mean_fish_totals$module_fish <- mean_fish_totals$`Module #`

fish_censreg <- censReg(
  total_biomass ~ Site_long*Shelter + module_fish,
  left = 0, right = Inf, data = mean_fish_totals )

summary( fish_censreg )
```

You can also estimate this specification with function tobit() of the "AER" package:

```
library( "AER" )
fish_tobit <- tobit(total_biomass ~ Site_long*Shelter + module_fish,
  data = mean_fish_totals)
summary( fish_tobit )
```

This gives identical results:

```
toMatrix <- function(x){ class( x ) <- "matrix"; x }
all.equal( toMatrix( coef( summary( fish_tobit ) ) ), 
  coef( summary( fish_censreg ) ), check.attributes = FALSE )
```

Residuals can be obtained from models estimated by tobit():

```
qqnorm( resid( fish_tobit ) ) 
qqline( resid( fish_tobit ) )
```

Please note that there are different ways to define (and, thus, calculate) residuals of censored regression models (See, e.g., the documentation of residuals.survreg() in the "survival" package, which is internally used when obtaining residuals of models estimated by tobit()).

Please don't hesitate to contact me if you (or anybody else) is interested in implementing currently missing features in the censReg package:
https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/sampleselection/

Comment: The (1|module) term is a random effect term that I run in all my models to account for repeated measures of the experimental units (modules) through time.  Is it not possible to have random effects in censReg models?  I need to account for this repeated measure design in my model.

Comment: Also I am receiving errors when I attempt to plot the qqplot for the censReg model to look for how well the model fits these data.  Do you have to use a different function or should this code work? 
```{r}
qqnorm(resid(fish_mixed_effects_censreg)) qqline(resid(fish_mixed_effects_censreg))
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to clarify what I need to do to incorporate random effects into the censReg model?  Or is it just not possible at this time?  I am by no means a coder so I wouldn't be much help in creating additions to the censReg package.

Comment: In order to implement model equations with something like "(1|module)" in censReg, one needs to figure out the log-likelihood function for this specification (i.e., find in the literature or derive it oneself), extend the current internal function in censReg() that calculates the log likelihood value so that it can also calculate the log-likelihood value for models with "(1|module)", implement that censReg() 'understands' "(1|module)" correctly, amend the documentation accordingly, and perhaps do some minor adjustments.